# SDL 2.0 Menu Function

Tags: c++, menu, sdl-2

I'm currently trying to write a menu function for one of my projects. I'm remaking pac-man and I'd like to be able to modularize the main menu, calling it when I want it to appear. I'm thinking an SDL_surface and a TTF font are all I need as parameters for this particular function.

I ran into trouble when I used SDL functions only available in SDL 1.2 as opposed to 2.0. I would like this code to be as reusable as possible. How would you guys approach this problem? I have some sample code below, though not all of it is my own. I'd like to get something like this working:

```
int showmenu(SDL_Surface* screen, TTF_Font* font)
{
  Uint32 time;
  int x, y;
  const int NUMMENU = 2;
  const char* labels[NUMMENU] = {"Continue","Exit"};
  SDL_Surface* menus[NUMMENU];
  bool selected[NUMMENU] = {0,0};
  SDL_Color color[2] = {{255,255,255},{255,0,0}};

  menus[0] = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,labels[0],color[0]);
  menus[1] = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,labels[1],color[0]);
  SDL_Rect pos[NUMMENU];
  pos[0].x = screen->clip_rect.w/2 - menus[0]->clip_rect.w/2;
  pos[0].y = screen->clip_rect.h/2 - menus[0]->clip_rect.h;
  pos[1].x = screen->clip_rect.w/2 - menus[0]->clip_rect.w/2;
  pos[1].y = screen->clip_rect.h/2 + menus[0]->clip_rect.h;

SDL_FillRect(screen,&screen>clip_rect,SDL_MapRGB(screen>format,0x00,0x00,0x00));

  SDL_Event event;
  while(1)
  {
    time = SDL_GetTicks();
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
      switch(event.type)
      {
        case SDL_QUIT:
        SDL_FreeSurface(menus[0]);
        SDL_FreeSurface(menus[1]);
        return 1;

    case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
    x = event.motion.x;
    y = event.motion.y;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUMMENU; i += 1)
    {

      if(x >= pos[i].x && x <= pos[i].x + pos[i].w &&
         y >= pos[i].y && y <= pos[i].y + pos[i].h)
      {
        if(!selected[i])
        {
          selected[i] = 1;
          SDL_FreeSurface(menus[i]);
          menus[i] = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,labels[i],color[1]);
        }
      }

      else
      {
        if(selected[i])
        {
          selected[i] = 0;
          SDL_FreeSurface(menus[i]);
          menus[i] = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,labels[i],color[0]);
        }
      }
    }
      break;

      case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      x = event.button.x;
      y = event.button.y;
      for(int i = 0; i < NUMMENU; i += 1)
      {
        if(x >= pos[i].x && x <= pos[i].x + pos[i].w &&
           y >= pos[i].y && y <= pos[i].y + pos[i].h)
        {
          SDL_FreeSurface(menus[0]);
          SDL_FreeSurface(menus[1]);
          return i;
        }
      }
      break;

      case SDL_KEYDOWN:
      if(event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
      {
        SDL_FreeSurface(menus[0]);
        SDL_FreeSurface(menus[1]);
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }

   for(int i = 0; i < NUMMENU; i += 1)
   {
     SDL_BlitSurface(menus[i],NULL,screen,&pos[i]);
   }

  }
}
```

Comment: So what is actually wrong with this code?

Comment: This code uses SDL 1.2 functions and it doesn't compile with SDL 2.0

Comment: Aside from obvious mistakes like `&screen>clip_rect` there is nothing here that was removed from SDL2.